# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: php, html, http

I am working in a php web site and my web server application is IIS on Windows Server 2003.

I added a web form that is needed to be saved and sent by email.

There are four files used to achieve that:-

> file1.php - to get the user inputs
>   through the form insisde it. file2.php
>   - to recieve the form data then save it in database using odbc and send
>   some of them by email file3.js - to
>   validate form elements file4.css - to
>   change the design and style of the web
>   page

I faced a strange error message which has not any reference to specific option or setting that I can change to solve the problem.

what I get is as the following:-

> HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

```
The website cannot display the page 
 HTTP 500  
   Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.

   What you can try: 
     Refresh the page. 

     Go back to the previous page. 

     More information
```

Comment: You should look for the web server's error log. It is likely to contain a more verbose error message

Comment: You must have more detailed information in the server log.

Comment: Check the PHP error log, post the last bit of that if it does not help

Comment: what if it is a shared hosting... the $5 per month or $10 per month type... can the error log be looked at in those cases I always wondered.

Comment: @動靜能量: Ask the hosting provider whether they provide access to hosting logs.

Answer (score 0):

Since at the moment there isn't much details in your question, I suggest you can do this:  1) try to print a "hello" in your PHP file and see if it works first, and if it does, then try the first few lines of your program, and print out something and see if it works or not.  In other words, reduce to the simplest and see if it works or not.  Then build on it gradually.

Comment: It's a lot easier to just look at the logs, then you can just fix the error straight away

Comment: what if it is a shared hosting... the $5 per month or $10 per month type... can the error log be looked at in those cases I always wondered.

Comment: +1 Logs are quicker, yes, but this is still a valid debugging technique, Adam.

Answer (score 0):

read IIS log

find IIS log in http://portal.smartertools.com/KB/a154/where-are-my-iis-log-files-stored.aspx